# Searching and displaying google results with searchBar:textDidChange:

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm searching stuff with Google in searchBar:textDidChange:

My issue is that everytime a letter is pressed, it waits to finish the last one to start the other one. And if the user types really fast - you get the idea - it searches for every letter every time, and updating the table (where the results relax) for every letter.

It's a real issue and it's extremely awful for the user.

Can you advice me to how efficiently search with searchBar:textDidChange:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**searchBar:textDidChange:** delegate method,  which gets called every time u modify the search bar.

Its usually used when table data is searched. As and when you type, the table data will be filtered.
For your case, its better to use when search button is pressed.